# Typo3 form submit to another view

Tags: forms, submit, typo3, fluid, extbase

I've made an extension in Typo3 6.2 with extbase and fluid.

I've 2 actions in my controller
- action 1 (single) : simply show an object and **a form** (some filter for object list)
- action 2 (list) : show the same form as in action 1 and treat form result and show a list of object

in my two views, my form looks like :

```
<f:form action="list" controller="MyController" pluginName="MyPluginName" name="myName">
...
</f:form>
```

the **MyPluginName** refere the the 2nd view (list)

When i submit the form from the 2nd view (list), the action recieve correctly the form params
But, when i submit it from the 1st view (single), i'm correctly redirected to the 2nd view BUT with a Typo3 Error :

```
 #1320830276: A hashed string must contain at least 40 characters, the given string was only 9 characters long. (More information)
```

So, how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a form, you have to set the action to **non-cacheable** in ext_localconf.